# How can I login to mysql root, using the normal user shell?

Tags: mysql

With my MySQL installation, I was able to install and update the password for my mysql root user. The weired behaviour which I notice is, when i run the command `mysql -u root -p`  from a normal user prompt, i only get the below error

```
ubuntu@node4:/var/log/mysql$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

But when I run the same command from the root prompt

```
ubuntu@node4:/var/log/mysql$ sudo su - root
root@node4:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I am able to login with root when running the `mysql -u root -p` command running from root user, could anyone advise me if I am missing on any configuration changes here. I want to use this as my database host and possibly like to use remote user connecting to this DB.

As commented by @Progman here is the output of the authentication plugin

```
mysql> SELECT Host, User, plugin FROM mysql.user
    -> ;
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+
| Host      | User             | plugin                |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | mysql.session    | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | root             | auth_socket           |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Based on the above situation, I am kind of not sure if this is the acceptable behavior?

TIA

Comment: This might be normal behaviour, depending on the [authentication plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pluggable-authentication.html) you are using, like `auth_socket`. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `SELECT Host, User, plugin FROM mysql.user` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `root` user in MySQL is using the [Socket Peer-Credential Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html), indicated by the identifier `auth_socket`. When used, the user is not authenticated by a password (like the [Caching SHA-2 Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html) indicated by `caching_sha2_password`), but instead is logging in with the username, the user is logged in into your host itself (like `ssh` or the normal login). This is for security reasons for the `root` account in MySQL, that you can only login from the `root` account of your system.

Depending on what you want to do, you can leave the `root` account (MySQL) as it is and only access the database with the `root` account (MySQL) when you logged in into your system on the `root` account (system). For any other MySQL account you can use the `caching_sha2_password` authentication plugin to have a normal `username`+`password` pair for login.